# Responsive form to a responsive image in bootstrap

Tags: css

I am trying to add a responsive form to a responsive background image. I want the form to be in an empty area in the image and to resize in the empty area itself when I resize my window. The below is the CSS code for the image and form text.

```
.image {
    background-image: url("src/assets/img/login_image.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    height: 100vh;
}

.form-text {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    bottom: 300px;

    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

Comment: This piece of code doesn't help anybody to debug, please create stackblitz, plunker working example with code or add some more code.

Comment: What pardeep said. Also, I would tag this question with css as it is unrelated to Angular..

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVvYeG.

Comment: Can somebody please help